# React class component not updating state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a SubmitEvent class component which uses a service class for retrieving venues using Axios.

```
  export default class SubmitEvent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
          loggedIn: undefined,
          venues: []
      }
      this.checkLoggedIn.bind(this);
      this.getVenues.bind(this);
  }
  checkLoggedIn = () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
    if (token === "") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  getVenues = async () => {
    let res = [];
    await Axios.get("/venues",{
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
      }
    })
    .then((response) =>{
      res = response.data
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return res;
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: this.checkLoggedIn(),
      venues: this.getVenues()
    });
    console.log(this.state.venues)
  }
}
```

If I am console logging the returned value in getVenues method the response is being shown. Although in the componentDidMount() the state for venues is is an empty array.
Why is this happening and how can I solve this?

Comment: This has nothing to do with React or state, you're trying to synchronously access an async result.

Comment: Yes, in the componentDidMount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call the `api` and when the promise is fulfilled, set your state.

```
export default class SubmitEvent extends React.Component {
  constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {
          loggedIn: undefined,
          venues: []
      }
      this.checkLoggedIn.bind(this);
      this.getVenues.bind(this);
  }
  checkLoggedIn = () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("auth-token");
    if (token === "") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  };
  getVenues = async () => {
    await Axios.get("/venues",{
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
      }
    })
    .then((response) =>{
       this.setState({ venues: response.data });
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
      loggedIn: this.checkLoggedIn(),
    });
    await this.getVenues();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `setState` inside `then`:

```js
getVenues = async () => {
    let res = [];
    await Axios.get("/venues",{
      headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
      }
    })
    .then((response) =>{
      res = response.data
      console.log(res)
      this.setState({venues: response.data})
    })

    .catch(err => console.log(err))
    return res;
  }
```

what you actually returned to `venues` in `componentDidMount` before, was a promise because of the `async` keyword  of `getVenues` method.